# Error running application that uses ms access database

Tags: visual-studio-2008, ms-access, ms-office

When I try to run my application I get:

**"The 'Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0' provider is not registered on the local machine."**

Is there a better way to make the call to the Microsoft access database that runs the application so that this error will not come up.  I would like the application to run on the machine even if Access is not installed.

Visual Studio 2008 - VB.Net is what I used to write it.

What method/technology should I use to make the call to Access db?

Answer (score 1):

For the easiest method, use an MDB file and use Jet 4.0, which is installed on all versions of Windows starting with Win2000.

One caveat: if you are compiling your app for 64-bit, you won't be able to use the installed Jet 4.0, since it's only 32-bit. The Access Database Engine download that @Conrad Frix cites will work for both MDB and ACCDB (the new file format for the ACE, i.e., the new version of Jet introduced with Access 2007), but if you're using MDB format for your data file, you'd only need it if you're compiling for 64-bit.

Comment: I am developing the application on a 64 bit Windows 7 version.  But I can set the application to compile for 32-bit when deployed and then I can use the Jet 4.0 still right?

Thanks

Comment: Yep -- compiling for 32-bit allows you to use the Jet 4.0 that is installed on all versions of Windows. If 64-bit compilation is required, then you'll have to install the 64-bit ACE (downloadable from MS), and then you could use ACCDB or MDB format.

Answer (score 0):

For machines without Office you can use [this](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?FamilyID=7554F536-8C28-4598-9B72-EF94E038C891&displaylang=en).